# Is there a function to split a large dataframe into n smaller dataframes of equal size (by row) and have an n+1 dataframe of smaller size?

Tags: r, split

The title pretty much states it. I have a data frame that has 7+million rows, far too big for me to analyze without my machine crashing. I want to split it into 100 smaller dataframes of with 70,000 rows, and have the 101th dataframe have the remaining rows (< 70,000). It seems that this is non-trivial.

I know I could manually calculating the size of the `n+1` dataframe, removing it, and then using the `split` function in the following way:

```
d <- split(my_data_frame,rep(1:100,each=70,000))
```

But I have multiple large dataframes and doing all these calculations is tedious. Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Do you want to write these to disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:723500, y = runif(7235000))
split(df, rep(1:100, each = round(NROW(df) / 100, -4)))
```

Or abstracting some more:

```
num_dfs <- 100
split(df, rep(1:num_dfs, each = round(NROW(df) / num_dfs, -4)))
```

You may want to consider something from the `caret` package such as: `caret::createFolds(df$x)`